# error while gradlew assembleDebug on react-native-serialport

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradlew

I tried to use https://github.com/mikafi/react-native-serialport

change build.gradle at node_modules\react-native-serialport\android
`implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['usbserial-6.0.5-release.aar'])`
to
`to implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'`

add

`implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'`

`implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'`

to build.gradle at android\app

and i try to add

`import com.melihyarikkaya.rnserialport;` not work

`import com.reactlibrary.RNSerialportPackage;` not work

any idea? this is the error

`MainActivity.java:6: error: package com.melihyarikkaya does not exist import com.melihyarikkaya.rnserialport; ^`

[react-native-serial error png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9PbV.png)

Answer (score 0):

the following package had a import problem, the lib was copyied over the /libs folder instead of using maven. I fixed it and rereleased on my branch.

https://github.com/Goostavo/react-native-serialport

Change your package on `package.json` to:

```
    "react-native-serialport": "github:goostavo/react-native-serialport",
```

Or check the changes on github and modify manually your package.

My branch is currently using the library default version 6.0.5. But checking on gradle you can update to 6.1.0.